# in matlab generate n random numbers between 0 and 1 that sum of them is less equal than one

Tags: random

I want to generate n random numbers between 0 and 1 that sum of them is less equal than one.
Sum(n random number between 0 and 1) <= 1
n?
For example: 3 random number between 0 and 1:
0.2 , 0.3 , 0.4 
0.2 + 0.3 + 0.4 = 0.9 <=1

Comment: Well, if you want then try to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would need to generate the numbers separately while keeping track of the previous numbers. We'll use your example:

1. Generate the first number between 0 and 1 = 0.2
2. 1.0 - 0.2 = 0.8: Generate the next number between 0 and 0.8 = 0.3
3. 0.8 - 0.3 = 0.5: Generate the next number between 0 and 0.5 = 0.4